# How to link Logic apps to Integration Service Environment through terraform

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I tried setting up logic app through terraform but I didn't get linking Logic apps to Integration Service Environment through terraform script

Answer (score 0):

Create an ISE first and pass the id to the workflow resource:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg-ise-workflows"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_integration_service_environment" "example" {
  name                 = "example-ise"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  // Removed other variables for readability
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
  name                               = "workflow1"
  location                           = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name                = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  integration_service_environment_id = azurerm_integration_service_environment.example.id
}
```